# Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform different versions

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, uwp, .net-core

I have an app, I have developer over some time, and today I was hoping for a release, but then it was complaining that I had to install `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v 5.3.0`, which I did, but then new errors occured.

If I am creating a new blank app, I can only find `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v 5.2.0` in NuGet.

What can I have done wrong?

Comment: Where have you found those versions? [The latest seems to be 5.1.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/)

Comment: I found 5.2 in NuGet last friday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.2.0 is [released on June 27, 2016](https://libraries.io/nuget/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/). However, [according to NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/5.2.0).

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

So it seems we still need to use 5.1.0 version by now. You can force to use 5.1.0 version by using following command.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform -Version 5.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e766a904-7346-4f76-bad2-852d3b301b0e/known-issue-version-52-of-microsoftnetcoreuniversalwindowsplatform-delisted-all?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues) known issue was posted regarding .NET Core 5.2.0. To workaround this limitation, you can downgrade the version of .NET Core that your project is targeting by right clicking on your project in the solution explorer and selecting "Manage NuGet Packages..."

In the NuGet Package Manager UI, you should be able to browse through all of your NuGet packages. Locate Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform, and use the NuGet Package Manager UI to change the version to 5.1.0.